# I am new to django i am not understanding class based views when we call {as_view ()} method in url pattern how the class methods are invoked

Tags: django, python-3.x

**urls.py**

```
  from django.urls import path   
  from myapp.views import MyView 
  urlpatterns = [path('about/', MyView.as_view()]
```

**views.py**

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse 
 from django.views import View class MyView(View):
 def get(self, request):
     # <view logic>
     return HttpResponse('result')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The as_view() method returns a function that can be called when a request arrives for the matching URL. This function will create an instance of the class (related to the view) then call its dispatch() function.

dispatch() tests whether it is a GET or a POST and relay it to the correct method.

Lets assume you have the following class-based view:

```
class MyExampleView(View):

     def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
             return my_get_response(request, *args, **kwargs)

     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
             return my_post_response(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If the request was a POST then post() is invoked by dispatch(), if it is a get then get() is invoked by dispatch().

Remember that get and post must return some sort of an HttpResponse.

More information can be found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation as_view() method is responsible for handling request and response

> classmethod as_view(**initkwargs): 
>    Returns a callable view that takes a request and returns a response

See this link: [Django Documentations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view)